# Error al construir Future captureImage(SelectSource opcion) async

Tags: flutter

```
 Future captureImage(SelectSource opcion) async {
    File image;

    opcion == SelectSource.camara
        ? image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera)
        : image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    setState(() {
      _foto = image;
    });
  }
```

Error: A value of type 'XFile' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'File'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'File'.dartinvalid_assignment

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que `_foto` sea un `File`. Debes de agarrar el path de la imagen de `image_picker`.

```
Future captureImage(SelectSource opcion) async {
    late XFile? image;

    opcion == SelectSource.camara
        ? image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera)
        : image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    setState(() {
      _foto = File(image!.path);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias !!!

Comment: Si resolvio el problema marca la respuesta como correcta.